SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does not exist error on 8th computer only
I have a wildcard certificate that I install on IIS as well as using netsh to bind the certificate to port 6286 for a self-hosted SignalR server.  I have done this since 2018 on 6 Azure VM 2019 and 2022 servers, a 2019 development server, and a Win 10 development laptop.
I just renewed the certificate on April 1 and successfully installed it on every server except the Win 10 laptop. I've used the same certificate file, intermediate certificate on it as all the others.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled both certificates but continue to get the "SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 A specified logon session does not exist" error using the following commands in an elevated command window (expired cert shown here):
netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6286
netsh http add sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:6286 appid={12345678-db90-4b66-8b01-88f7af2e36bf} certhash=426a467d86b1cc7371a805faac30071f4fe478ba
SSL Certificate add failed, Error: 1312 
A specified logon session does not exist

This certificate was installed and bound successfully on IIS.  I just can't get it to bind to port 6286. Obviously, I know where to put the cert in MMC, the .cer in local computer, personal, certificates and the intermediate cert, gd-g2_iis_intermediates.p7b, in local computer, Intermediate Certification Authorities, just like the other 7 computers.
An interesting thing is I tried to reinstall last year's certificate on the laptop and it fails with the same error.  I reinstalled its .cer file too and still the error using the certificate that worked when I started this effort.  So, whatever I've done, I've really messed things up. I'm guessing I uninstalled something I shouldn't have but don't know what.
So, where am I messing up?

I knew if I posted something here, I'd find the answer.  I read a post that said with this error, check the icon and it showed one just like mine.  It said it didn't have the private key and needed to add the .pfx.  So, I imported the .pfx file into local computer, certificates, personal and it worked.
